# Semi-open sets of $R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> S is semi open if there exist an open set O s.t. $O\subset S \subset \bar{O}$ or $S\subset Cl(IntS)$,

Then clearly all open intervals are semi open and thus their union. $(a,b]$ and $[a,b)$ are also semi open and so is $[a,b]$ and there unions. Is that it, only finite sets are not semi open and everything else is?

Comment: It's clear that any interval is semi-open, but not for the reason you say: $(a,b]$ is not the union of a collection of open intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $S$ Cantor set.

Then Cantor set is nowhere dense i.e. Cantor set is closed and contains no non empty open sets.

Then Cantor set doesn't satisfy any condition of your definition of semi open sets.

In fact whole collection of nowhere dense sets in $\Bbb{R}$ excluded from the class of all semi open sets.

Comment: *nonempty nowhere dense sets

Answer (score 0):

The rationals are an infinite set in the reals and do not contain any nonempty open set. As they are not contained within the closure of any open set within them they are not semi open by the definition.

As far as non-singleton intervals go, it seems that yes all such intervals are semi open.